# Reading saving PytQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I started learning PyQt5 and somehow wrote a save for QTableWidget and Qlineedit, but I ran into the problem of reading table data from saving, I know that I need to use the value function to take the name of the value of each element in the table, but I don't know how to formulate it, I will be glad to help

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QCoreApplication
CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config.ini'

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1920, 1000)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 131, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setInputMask("")
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Регион...")
        
        self.saveButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.saveButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 940, 90, 23))
        self.saveButton.setObjectName("pushButton_save")
        self.saveButton.clicked.connect(self.slotButton_save)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 0, 1720, 1000))
        
        self.loadButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget) 
        self.loadButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 940, 90, 23))
        self.loadButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.loadButton.clicked.connect(self.slotButton_Load)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 0, 1720, 1000))
        
        Row = 1000
        self.row = Row
        Col = 7
        self.col = Col
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(Row)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(Col)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(5, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(6, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(237)
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def slotButton_save(self):
        setting = QtCore.QSettings("config.ini", QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)

        setting.setValue("edit/edit",
                         self.lineEdit.text())
        countColumn = 0  
        while countColumn < self.tableWidget.columnCount():
            for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
                try:
                    setting.setValue(f"Column{countColumn}/{i}", self.tableWidget.item(i, countColumn).text())
                except AttributeError:
                    setting.setValue(f"Column{countColumn}/{i}", "empty")
            countColumn += 1

            
    def slotButton_Load(self):
        setting = QtCore.QSettings("config.ini", QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)

        setting.value("edit/edit"," ")
        countColumn = 0  
        while countColumn < self.tableWidget.columnCount():
            for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
                try:
                    set.self.tableWidget(setting.setValue(f"Column{countColumn}/{i}", ))
                except AttributeError:
                    setting.setValue(f"Column{countColumn}/{i}", )
            countColumn += 1

         
    

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.saveButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сохранить"))
        self.loadButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "загрузить"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Регион"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Адрес"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Предприятие"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ассортимент"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Количество"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(5)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Результат"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(6)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Примечание"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: There are many issues with your code. First of all, `set.self.tableWidget` doesn't mean anything, since [`set`](//docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) is a python type; then, if you want to *get* values from QSettings, you must use `value()`, not `setValue()`; and if you need to *set* table widget items, you must use [`setItem()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setItem); finally, you should *not* edit pyuic files, but instead follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: so?:setting.value(f"Column{countColumn}/{i}", self.tableWidget.setItem(i, countColumn))

Comment: When I want a GUI for an INI file, I've had good luck with [this project](https://github.com/pafcu/ConfigObj-GUI). Instead of QSettings it uses the well known [ConfigObj module](https://github.com/DiffSK/configobj). This doesn't make use of a table, but instead generates a window with labels and different input widgets on the fly. It's curious that that there are no convenience functions built into Qt to hook up QSettings to a GUI or even a QTableModel.

Comment: If you're comforable working with databases, another idea would be to put data into a SQLite table and read it into a QSqlTableModel. From a table model it's easy to display data.